# values are not getting passed from one function to another in python class inside airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

i am creating python class for dynamic task generation. for that 1st i am accepting the input from user and passing that input for dynamic task creation part but i am not able to update the class variable inside function. in below code 1st i am calling  accept_ip_cli  and expecting that this function will update self.my_dict variable but this is not happening when i am trying to read self.my_dict  inside test_dict_value() i am getting empty dictionary.

```py
class my_class:


    def __init__(self,
                 airflow_cfg, dag,
                 default_args,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):


        self.master_config_yaml = ''
        self.my_dict = {}
        self.dag = dag
        self.default_args = default_args
        self.tasks = []
        self.config_values = []
        self.config_key_value = {}
        self.job_id = None

        self.insert_query = ""
        self.config_key = ['']

    # def read_yaml(path):
    #     with open(path, 'r') as f:
    #         df = pd.json_normalize(safe_load(f))
    #     return df

    def accept_ip_cli(self, **kwargs):
        scope = kwargs["dag_run"].conf.get("scope", "dm")
        pod = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('pod', 'acc')
        layer = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('layer', 'layer')
        pipeline_name = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('pipe', 'all')
        kpi = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('d', 'data')
        my_dict = {"scope": scope.lower().strip(), "pod": pod.lower().strip(), "layer": layer.lower().strip(),
                   "pipeline_name": pipeline_name.lower().strip(), "kpi": kpi}

        self.my_dict = my_dict
        return self.my_dict

    def test_dict_value(self, my_dictionary, **kwargs):
        print('Dict is', my_dictionary)

        return self.my_dict

    def call_accepted_ip(self):
        return PythonOperator(task_id="accept_input_from_cli",
                              provide_context=True,
                              python_callable=self.accept_ip_cli,
                              dag=self.dag)

    def test_dict(self):
        return PythonOperator(task_id="test_dict",
                              provide_context=True,
                              python_callable=self.test_dict_value,
                              dag=self.dag)


def get_json_var(AIRFLOW_VAR):
    aiflow_cfg = Variable.get(AIRFLOW_VAR, deserialize_json=True)
    return aiflow_cfg


# Function to create dags for the number of executions
def create_dag(pipeline_name):
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'Airflow'
    }
    dag_id = "recon_nik_poc2"

    dag = DAG(
        dag_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1
    )
    airflow_cfg = get_json_var(AIRFLOW_VAR)

    bq = my_class(airflow_cfg, dag=dag, default_args=default_args)
    start_flow = DummyOperator(task_id='start_flow', dag=dag)

    end_flow = DummyOperator(task_id='end_flow', dag=dag)

    start_flow >> bq.call_accepted_ip() >> bq.test_dict() >> end_flow
    return dag


pipelines_names = ['recon_nik_poc2']
for each in pipelines_names:
    dag_name = "recon_nik_poc2"
    globals()[dag_name] = create_dag(each)
```

what i am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every task there will be a new instance of `AuditReconciliationFW` thus what `bq.call_accepted_ip()` does will not propagate to `bq.test_dict()`. If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve is to pass a value from one task to another. To do that you have to use [XCom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) as that's the only right way to share state between tasks.

Comment: here i am just testing this value. i want to use these values in another function which is generating dynamic task for me and that function is get called directly without any python operator so i cant use xcom there.  can you suggest any another way where i can use ip given from cli is pass to this class

Comment: As I said - to pass values from one operator to other you have to use XCom. You can  pass output of `call_accepted_ip` as argument to `test_dict`. Moreover as you are using `PythonOperator` I would recommend familiarising with [taskflow api](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from one function to another, you can use `XCom`. By default the tasks are isolated, but XCom allows you to communicate with each other. It is very useful and simple to use